# R: library(ks) - bug or not?

Tags: r, crash

In my program, I need to have a function, that makes continuous density estimate (defined everywhere on reals) from arbitrary sample. So I've chosen the `library(ks)` and found that it sometimes produces buggy object, and other functions (e.g. `plot`) crash R session while accessing it.

Please, I want someone else to check whether it is a bug in the package, my R build, (or even I'm doing something wrong).

So, the code to reproduce the crash :

```
library(ks) 

set.seed(8192)


density_generator<-function(s)
{
  # this function returns kernel density estimate built on sample 's' 
  hpi1 <- hpi(x=s) # calculating h parameter for kernel estimation
  fhat.pi1 <- kde(x=s, H=hpi1) # generating density object
  fhat.pi1
}

## testing the density generator
conditional_density_object<-density_generator(c(1,2,3,4,5))

foo<-function(z){predict(conditional_density_object,x=z)}

y<-seq(from=-7,to=11, by=0.01)  # R session fails for some of the parameters

plot(y,sapply(y,foo),pch=".")
```

Other parameters, e.g. `y<-seq(from=-7,to=5, by=0.01)` do not crash the R session:
[image: Rplot]

If everything works Ok for the range (-7,11) - please, check other (large) numbers, maybe this is system-specific.

Comment: Your function does not seem to be well defined. From what I can see, its return value is a function, not a numerical vector as you probably meant it. In addition, the function uses an object named `y` that isn't defined anywhere within the function or provided as an argument. Try dropping the `function(y)` thing in the last line enclosing the `predict` call, and include `y` as an argument to the main function.

Comment: @SimonG  No, I need exactly a function(y) that is kernel estimate. I have just used the vector for testing. The second "y" in global scope has nothing in common with function definition, it seems just a [usual syntax](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html) to define function in R.  Can you please post an answer with the code, how you think it should be?

Comment: @SimonG My function `density_generator` evaluates the function I need (density estimate), which is computationally expensive. If I move `y` inside, it will just recompute the estimate each time, which is very slow.

Comment: @SimonG Updated post - changed the variable name to `z`, crash persists.

Comment: I didn't say anything about syntax, my point was that your code doesn't mean what you think it means. At the end of `density_generator`, you define a function without assigning it to a name. Functions are objects in R, and calling things like `function(y) y` does not return `y` but the function object itself. If you want the function to return the result of `predict(fhat.pi1,x=y)`, then you should have that as the last line (or alternatively `return(predict(fhat.pi1,x=y))`, and you should include `y` in the functions arguments. Like this, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @SimonG Ok, I have edited my question to separate objects. I want to mention one more time, that *it works* for the range (-7,5) for example. In my program I need not a numerical vector, but a function that I will use for sampling.